# Exclude PHP from output from WYSIWYG in CMS

Tags: php, content-management-system, wysiwyg

I'm writing a basic CMS for one of my sites and have run into an issue where some pages need to dynamically serve PHP and JS, where as others are plain HTMl. I want there to be a setting which will allow this for the pages that need it and will load ACE editor instead of a different wysiwyg editor. The challenge here is that on the pages which I do not explicitly tell it there will be code, I want to reject any inputs that code. I can set it up to insert a for all pages without JS, but how can I keep php code from running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question, you'd need to use htmlentities instead of php tags

```
<? ?>
&lt;? ?&gt;
```